# Django app on EC2 ubuntu Static File issue

Tags: django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have recently uploaded my app on EC2 server running Ubuntu, Python 2.7.3, django.VERSION 1.5.1. I have managed to successfully launch it without any CSS/Images or JS. I can view templates and navigate them means template directory settings are working.
Looks like I am missing some setting for static/media files.
Can anyone please advise?

**Content of "cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf"**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/site/ProjectName/ProjectName/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/site/ProjectName

<Directory /home/ubuntu/site/ProjectName/ProjectName>
<Files wsgi.py> 
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

**Content of settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/media/'
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/var/www/static/admin/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/var/www/static',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/var/www/templates',)


**$ ls -ltr /var/www**
```

total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root  177 Jul 26 20:21 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data root 4096 Jul 28 04:20 static
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data root 4096 Jul 28 04:20 media
drwxr-xr-x 20 www-data root 4096 Jul 28 16:29 templates

**Errors in apache2/access.log**

[29/Jul/2013:13:41:36 -0500] "GET /static/neatadmin/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798 
[29/Jul/2013:13:41:36 -0500] "GET /static/neatadmin/css/jquery.fancybox.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1806 
[29/Jul/2013:13:41:36 -0500] "GET /static/neatadmin/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1798 
[29/Jul/2013:13:41:36 -0500] "GET /static/neatadmin/js/jquery.metadata.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1804 
[29/Jul/2013:13:41:36 -0500] "GET /static/neatadmin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1794 
[29/Jul/2013:13:41:36 -0500] "GET /static/neatadmin/js/error.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1794

**Errors in apache2/error.log (I dont think it's relevant but just FYI)**

[Mon Jul 29 13:41:29 2013] [error] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py:221: DeprecationWarning: You have no filters defined on the 'mail_admins' logging handler: adding implicit debug-false-only filter. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#request-exceptions-are-now-always-logged
[Mon Jul 29 13:41:29 2013] [error]   DeprecationWarning)
[Mon Jul 29 13:41:29 2013] [error] 
[Mon Jul 29 13:41:35 2013] [error] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py:221: DeprecationWarning: You have no filters defined on the 'mail_admins' logging handler: adding implicit debug-false-only filter. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#request-exceptions-are-now-always-logged
[Mon Jul 29 13:41:35 2013] [error]   DeprecationWarning)
[Mon Jul 29 13:41:35 2013] [error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings are confusing the purpose of `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT`. `STATICFILES_DIRS` holds additional static resources that are global to your project. This mirrors the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. This directory would be included in your source repository.

`STATIC_ROOT` is a collection point for serving static files in production. Files from all the installed apps and `STATICFILES_DIRS` are copied here when you run `collectstatic`. This does not need to be set for local development. This directory would not be included in the repo as it only contains generated content. Your webserver configuration should have an alias to serve `STATIC_ROOT` as `STATIC_URL` For an example using Apache you should see the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: thanks a lot Mark, I was able to follow documentation and was able to fix issue by updating httpd.conf